# nodejs gremlin output edge json structure changes

Tags: node.js, gremlin

```
g.E().hasLabel('abc')
```

Above is the query to list edges and the output format is:

```
[
                    {
                        "id": "94bbb5fa-0aab-c333-d85c-0bd5a4993167",
                        "label": "abc",
                        "outV": {
                            "id": "1eebe37d-f239-4954-bc6c-20bacbedba5f",
                            "label": "Device"
                        },
                        "inV": {
                            "id": "68b99909-19e2-c3c9-0305-ff6925463c09",
                            "label": "UseCase"
                        },
                        "properties": {}
                    }]
```

it has been 2 years the structure does not change, however when we build the npm package on dev server today, the output changes to:

```
[{
                        "id": "94bbb5fa-0aab-c333-d85c-0bd5a4993167",
                        "label": "abc",
                        "outV": "1eebe37d-f239-4954-bc6c-20bacbedba5f",
                        "inV": "68b99909-19e2-c3c9-0305-ff6925463c09",
                        "properties": {}
}]
```

the outV and inV are changed to string rather than an object.
there could be some nodejs npm package upgrade causing this? I am using "gremlin": "3.4.6".
is there a way I can specify the edge output in nodejs?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the changes on my local build by upgrading to latest npm 8.1.2 and nodejs 16.13.1 version, but still have no clue which exact package causing the changes.

Comment: fixed the issue by upgrading the gremlin npm package to 3.5.1.